# Origen de la palabra "suripanta"

Tags: etimología

El DLE recoge [**suripanta**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ynp9B0L) como

> 1. f. despect. Mujer ruin, moralmente despreciable.
> 2. f. desus. Mujer que actuaba de corista o de comparsa en el teatro.

Por otro lado he visto en el NTTLE que la primera vez que aparece es en el diccionario de 1925, con las mismas acepciones, pero en orden inverso:

> Mujer corista en un teatro. || 2. despect. Mujer baja, moralmente despreciable.

En el CORDE apenas hay una decena de casos, de los que el más antiguo es de 1868 (Enrique Gaspar: La chismosa: comedia en tres actos y en verso: "... O en el teatro del Circo; porque él va allí a hacer el oso a una **suripanta**; ¡y digo! que la hace cada presente... ")

¿De dónde viene la palabra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ### suripanta
>
> #### Etimología
>
> Acuñada como parte de un coro sin sentido por el escritor español Eugenio Blasco para la opereta *El joven Telémaco*, estrenada en 1866 en Madrid <sup>[1]</sup>
>
> <sup>1. Hernández Vista, Eugenio (1972) "Un fenómeno concreto de semantización en español". *Revista Española de Lingüística,* 2(1):35–44</sup>

- https://es.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/suripanta

Answer (score 3):

Por ampliar un poco [la respuesta de @tjfuke](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/24203/12637), que solo cita a la Wikipedia, comentar que en el fichero general de la RAE vienen varias tarjetas que hacen mención a la palabra *suripanta*. Algunas nos confirman que la palabra fue, efectivamente, una invención de Eugenio Blasco para su opereta *El joven Telémaco*. Una en particular me hizo descubrir [el siguiente texto](https://es.wikisource.org/wiki/Memorias_%C3%8Dntimas,_Cap%C3%ADtulo_XII_-_Los_bufos,_do%C3%B1a_Rosa) que nos da más detalles:

> No creó solamente un género [Arderius](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisco_Arderius), creó una docena de mujeres bonitas con una pierna al aire cada una; coristas de nuevo aspecto, a quienes el público les dió nombre. Por aquello de que cantaban en el Telémaco un coro en griego macarrónico en el que dominaba la palabra *suripanta*, que no quería decir nada, las coristas de Arderius se llamaron suripantas, y fueron lo menos la mitad del éxito del género y del teatro.

En la hemeroteca del BNE las primeras referencias a la palabra nos confirman su origen:

> *Saffo* es una señorita que después de componer muy buenos versos en griego (y no como aquellos de *Suripanta, la suripanta*) se enamora como una desesperada y llega al estremo de echar los trastos á rodar.
>
> **Gil Blas.** 18/10/1866, [página 1](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0003831736&page=1&search=suripanta&lang=es).

Se pueden encontrar también ese mismo año algunas críticas a la obra del *Telémaco* que hacen mención al *suripanta* para referirse a la parte en la que el coro canta la palabra, mencionando que *enlevá le public* [sic] y comenzando a dar forma al significado posterior de la misma. Buen coro debía ser para levantar al público.

Como curiosidad, el tratado *Lenguaje y discriminación sexual* de Álvaro García Meseguer, de 1977, incluye la palabra *suripanta* con su acepción de "mujer ruin, moralmente despreciable", y el comentario "otro despectivo sin dual masculino".